# Onchangetext callback remove on unmount not possible

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How can I remove react native onchangetext callback on textinput when component unmount? Because it leaks memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't see your code, so i don't know if my answer will fit all your cases. My guts feeling is

- if you use `useEffect`, there's an unmount in official documentation
- you can try to add a `ref` for this component to detect if this component is alive or not

I'll provide an example for second case,

```
  const ref = useRef()
  const onClick = {
    if (ref.current) {
       // if it's still mounted, let's rock
    }
  }

  return <MyComponent ref={ref} onClick={onClick} />
```

Comment: Hey, how can i use `ref` to contain a value like a state?
I'm trying to achieve [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64129237/how-to-change-text-immediately-in-onchangetext-callback) if can be done with `ref`