# How to change text immediately in onChangeText Callback?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a case i want to do "Write Time"

So I have a TextInput user can write a time "numbers"
now as usually i set state with new char using onChangeText
So now i want to replace the third character user typed with `:` immediately and continue other numbers

So the final result should be

user type 123
should change to 12: immediately then continue `12:45`

But i can't achieve it :(

code snippet

```
 const [daysSelected, setDaysSelected] = useState([]);

// sample state after manipulated

     daysSelected = [{
        id: 1,
        day: "Sunday",
        morning: ['', ''],
        evening: ['', ''],
     }]

 <TextInput
        placeholder="07:00"
        maxLength={5}
        ref={ref}
        style={styles.inputTime}
        placeholderTextColor="#707070"
        value={String(daysSelected[item.id]?.morning[0])}
        onChangeText={(text) => {
           
            setDaysSelected((prevState) => {

                  let x = prevState[item.id].morning[0].replace(3, ':');
                  console.log('shouldReplaced?', x); // not works well :\ 
                  console.log('txt', prevState[item.id]?.morning[0]);
                  prevState[item.id].morning[0] = text;
                  return [...prevState];
            });
        }
   />
```

Comment: Why are the `morning` and `evening` values arrays of 2 strings? Shouldn't it just be one string, the time they type?

Comment: @Jayce444 sadly no, it's start/end work time in morning/evening

Comment: It's kinda hard predicting it in real time. Cos what if they type `125`, they could mean `1:25` or could be typing `12:50`. Probably better to just do it either once they've typed all 4 numbers, or on blur

Comment: @Jayce444 Interesting, I don't think about `1:25`, hmm u mean when user type 1234 without `:` so should I added it on blur?UH, Really it's hard maybe they've type 1:23 :(

Comment: I think it would be better to keep it 4 digits always and if the input blurred on 3 digit pad start with 0.

Comment: @SaachiTech i guess it's not like a time if i keep it 4 so when user type 123 it's not like a time so that's why i keep it 5 ( 12:13 ) it a time here..

Comment: I mean If someone type 123 then add a leading 0 to the string which will make it 0123 and then you can add a colon at third place to make it 01:23, that is a time

Comment: @SaachiTech Nice, I will do it when arriving home, now can you write an answer with ur idea and worked code snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To this fix this problem here is an approach I suggest:

1. Make sure we always have 4 digit number in the input
2. If the user makes the text input blurred after entering less then 4 digits add leading zeros to make the input as 4 digit

Here is a simple snippet of code to achieve this.

```
const [inputTime, setTime] = React.useState(null);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TextInput
        maxLength={5}
        placeholder="07:00"
        placeholderTextColor="#707070"
        onBlur={(e) => {
          let { text } = e.nativeEvent;
          let values = text.split(":");
          let value = "";
          if(values.length==1){
            value = values[0].substring(0,4).padStart(4, 0);
            value = value.substring(0, 2) + ':' + value.substring(2);
            setTime(value);
          }else if(values.length==2){
            value = `${values[0].padStart(2, 0)}:${values[1].padEnd(2, 0)}`;
            setTime(value);
          }
          else{
            console.log('wrong input')
          }
        }}
      />
      <Text>{`Formatted time is ${inputTime}`}</Text>
    </View>
  );
```

Here is the Snack https://snack.expo.io/@saachitech/477b89

Tested with below conditions

```
Input 123 will be converted to 01:23
Input 1234 will be converted to 12:34
Input 12121 will be converted to 12:12
Input 12:1 will be converted to 12:10
Input 1:23 will be converted to 01:23
Input 12:23 won't have any effect and remain 12:23
Input 01:23 won't have any effect and remain 01:23
```

Comment: Thanks, it's `let {text} = e.nativeEvent;` 
But now we've faced some other case :"D 
if user type 1:22
onBlur will return 1::22 "twice `:`" :\

Comment: ah, was testing on web expo. Added a condition to replace ':' if the user inserted it.

Comment: Thanks i solve it before you using includes :"D, nevermind, 
another case user type 
01:2 => they need 01:20 but we have max 4!

Comment: Updated my answer with more conditions

Comment: but you append 0 in the end! we not sure they want 20 maybe they wnat 25! 
so in this case, in ur code, it will 01:20 Not 01:25, And actually max length 4 so the user can't write the last digit :) and we suppose it zeroes 

Anyway, I solve the issue i will add the correct code achieve my cases in question check it, And Thank you for help ;)

Comment: Max length can be 5 anyway

Comment: Yes but if i type `12345` in your code will convert to `12:345` check my solve above and u will understand what I meant

Comment: I check snack you're Right :)) another case in your code you miss is 1:222 ;) => 01:22